# Javafx Robot not working from Javafx 2.2

Tags: java, automation, javafx, javafx-2

Looks like  com.sun.glass.ui.Robot   is not working anymore in Javafx 2.2.

Is there any other alternative?

I've moved over to AWT robot, but that does not seem to be the best solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Glass (FX) robot works for me in 2.2. Try next:

```
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Button");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(btn), 300, 250);

    stage.setTitle(VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setX(100);
    stage.setY(100);
    stage.show();

    Robot robot = com.sun.glass.ui.Application.GetApplication().createRobot();
    robot.mouseMove(130, 130);
    robot.mousePress(1);
    robot.mouseRelease(1);
}
```

If you want public API for it to be added you can vote for next issue: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-17571