# JavaFX able to control window components?

Tags: javafx

I have a general question regarding to JavaFX.
I am wondering if it is able to control window components such as file download / upload dialog (i.e: When you are using Internet Explorer, you may need to upload/download files. I want to automate the operation hopefully with javaFX). If they are possible, could you please, point me where to look?

Comment: Are you looking for a [FileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is functionality similar to [`java.awt.Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html). JavaFX doesn't provide an API for this, but you can still use Glass to use Robot, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950551/javafx-robot-not-working-from-javafx-2-2) and [this issue on javafx-jira](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-17571)